# Is the height of all binary trees with average depth of O(logn) for all nodes, also O(logn)?

Tags: binary-tree

If the height of all the binary trees with average depth of O(logn), is also O(logn) is true, I need to prove it. If it isn't correct I'm asked to find a group of trees which have an average depth of O(logn) but their height is not O(logn). Since O is calculated asymptoticaly the group of trees must be general and not specific (for expample not trees with 10 nodes).

Comment: Sounds more like https://cs.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a computer programming question. It is a computer science or graph theory question.

Answer (score 0):

> If the height of all the binary trees with average depth of O(logn),
>   is also O(logn)

No, that's not true.

> If it isn't correct I'm asked to find a group of trees which have an
>   average depth of O(logn) but their height is not O(logn).

[Basically the group of randomly generated BST could suite your needs.](https://pages.cpsc.ucalgary.ca/~jacobs/Courses/cpsc331/F08/notes/lecture17.pdf)

If `c` is a positive integer, `n` is sufficiently large, and `T` is a randomly
constructed BST with size `n`, then the probability that

```
height(T) ≥ 3c log N
```

is less than 1/c.